# Symfony2: Assert Image / File type detection not working

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony 2.5 and have extended the fos user entity with a picture and a non-mapped file property:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="picture", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $picture;


    /**
     * @Assert\Image(maxSize="2M")
     */
    private $file;
```

Adding the file field to the form renders a text field

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm();
```

But this makes it work

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('file', 'file')
        ->getForm();
```

Symfon2 documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) says here that it should automatically detect the form field type as "file" based on the annotation.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a known bug?

Comment: So this work: $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('file', 'file')
        ->getForm();
? Your problem is little unclear. I've read the documentation and it is detailed like every time.

Comment: Yes, `->add('file', 'file')` works.  
  
But the documentation says that the type should be auto recognized based on the annotation..  
So `->add('file')` should have worked - but it did not.  
  
Now I have to pass the field type to the function which I was looking to avoid.